# Formula to sort and filter 4 digit numbers with 2 or more of the same digits

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Id like to use a filter and sort formula to filter out and sort all numbers that have two or more of the same number. they are all 4 digit numbers.

```
0055  
0121  
1134  
2352  
3411
```

this is just an example list of the output I would need.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `numList` with the range you're sorting on. (Or use `numList` as a named range for your input set.)

```
=SORT(FILTER(numList,
  (LEN(SUBSTITUTE(numList,LEFT(numList,1),""))<>3)
  +(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(numList,MID(numList,2,1),""))<>3)
  +(MID(numList,3,1)=RIGHT(numList,1))))
```

Filter conditions:

1. `(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(numList,LEFT(numList,1),""))<>3)` Checks if the first digit is repeated.
2. `(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(numList,MID(numList,2,1),""))<>3)` Checks if the second digit is repeated.
3. `(MID(numList,3,1)=RIGHT(numList,1))` Checks if digits 3 and 4 are the same. We can take this shortcut because we've already checked the first two digits at this point.

If any of these is true, then we have a repeating digit.